# Finding other vaults in Fallout Shelter

Tags: fallout-shelter

In Fallout Shelter can you find other vaults at anytime in the game? And if so do you attack them as if you are a raider or what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quests](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_Shelter_quests) involve a team of dwellers leaving your vault and visiting some pre-determined location to achieve some objectives and/or follow a story line. Many of the locations are other vaults, so yes, other vaults are found in Fallout Shelter.

As to what you do when you get there, it's mostly killing raiders and/or creatures that have invaded, while searching for loot and/or survivors.

[image: Meeting dwellers in another vault]

Comment: It doesn't say anywhere that you're going to other vault ?

Comment: @ИвоНедев you don't believe me? The link is provided as further reading, not as proof. Regardless, it does contain the description of every quest, some of which refer to other vaults.

Comment: @OrangeDog Thanks a bunch! Ironically soon after I asked the question I found a vault to explore in quests (They look very different to the ones we overseer) But thanks a lo!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [OrangeDog's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/287120/73976) general exploration also offers the chance of discovering a Vault or dwelling to explore, similar to Quests.

Comment: did you actually find a *vault* as random encounter during exploration,@Ben? http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_Shelter_random_encounters